# How to convert Matlab indexing to Python

Tags: python, matlab, indexing

```
data_tp0 = xlsread(append(con,'_',treatment,string(hrt),'_t',string(tps(1)),'_analysis.xlsx'));
Time_tp0=data_tp0(:,1);

signal_tp0=(data_tp0(:,2));
% signal = sin(Time);   %%  Raw signal with time period of ~6.5 sec i.e. Freq = 1/6.5 = 0.15 Hz
L = length(Time_tp0);
Fs= L/max(Time_tp0);     % Sampling frequency                    
T = 1/Fs;             % Sampling period  


Y_tp0 = fft(signal_tp0);                          % Compute DFT of Signal and get real and imaginary components
P2_tp0 = abs(Y_tp0/L);                            % Whole spectrum
P1_tp0 = P2_tp0(1:L/2+1);                         % One-sided spectrum
P1_tp0(2:end-1) = 2*P1_tp0(2:end-1);              % Even-valued signal length L.
```

What does the one-sided spectrum line mean? Specifically the

```
1:L/2+1 inside of the P2_tp0(1:L/2+1)
```

What does this indexing mean? What is its equivalent in python?

Similarly what does the indexing mean for this line of code and its equivalent in python?

```
P1_tp0(2:end-1) = 2*P1_tp0(2:end-1)
```

Comment: in Python you can also use `data[1:L/2+1]` which means `start = 1` , `end = L/2+1` `data[start:end]`. And if you use `numpy.array` with 2D array then you can use even `array[y_start:y_end, x_start:x_end]` or `array[y_start:y_end, x_index]` or `array[ : , x_index]` like in `data_tp0(:,2)`

Comment: also note that matlab's indexing is end-inclusive whereas python is not. `a[1:3]` in matlab is 3 elements while `a[1:3]` in numpy is 2 elements.

Comment: in matlab start:stop is ussually used as a vector creation or to indexin an existing vector, in this case you are using the second one... here you are going from the first index of the vector to the index L/2+1.. in python you could do the same calling `P2_tp0[0:L/2]` or just `P2_tp0[:L/2]` you are getting a piece of the original vector (or array).

Comment: Note also matlab indexes start from `1` while python starts from `0`